# setContentView from another Class method

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to show a layout from another class method, but the only way I've found for doing this was through 
    `startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,User.class));`

The problem is, by doing that way, I can only use the `onCreate()` method from my User class and the method I want to use is chooseUser.

On my main class (Login):

```
if (userSenha.equals(senhaBanco)) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,User.class));
}
```

On my User class:

```
public class User extends Login {
public void chooseUser() {
    setContentView(R.layout.escolheuser);
}
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.escolheuser);
}
}
```

Is there a way to choose which method I'm going to call when using startActivity?
Or should I use another way to show the screen?
I'm brand new to Java and Android so, sorry if i said something wrong.

Edit:
What I'm trying to achieve is:
From my first Class (named Login) call a method named chooseUser from another class named User and this method shows a new screen.

Comment: You need to do some more reading, perhaps a good Android development book.  A layout is nothing more than a UI definition.  A layout can exist without an Activity.  An Activity can exist without a layout.  An Activity can use multiple layouts.  So given this, your question makes no sense.  I recommend editing your question and focus on *what* you are trying to do and *why*, then ask how to achieve it.  Use as few words as possible and be accurate.  Remember that the people reading these questions know nothing except what you put into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are so many ways to manage the navigation of your app.

the main ways are:

1. activities.
2. fragments.
3. as you've written, a customized way, using setContentView on the activity that you are currently staying. this is not recommended, since you have to do a lot of work in order to manage everything, including what happens when the configuration changes (like orientation changes) and what happens when the app gets resumed after a long time.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but since its not the best way to do it, how should I make it?

Comment: as i've already written, you can use activities or fragments. it's really not that hard. just check the API demos for the activities samples, or the support library samples for the fragments examples. recently google has also introduced another cool way to navigate - using a navigation drawer. you have to choose which method is best for your app. each has its own advantages and disadvantages.